# Bazel build air gapped

Tags: bazel

I try to build  a project, with uses Bazel. On that machine there is no internet connection (Open Build System). So I have to download the needed packages before the build.

I tried to use "--repository_cache" and stored the downloaded files from an online instance there, but the air gapped system always trys to download the files.

Is there an other way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dependency archiving for airgapped network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61820038/dependency-archiving-for-airgapped-network)

Comment: Not really or better: I don't know. If I understand right, I package all dependencies, that bazel needs. That is already done, there are suse packages for this. But the libedgetpu needs additional dependencies which it pulls at build time from several git repos. And this dependencies (tensorflow, coral_crosstool, io_bazel_rules_closure) are needes cause there is no internet connection.

Comment: Put also your transitive dependencies into —dist-dir

Comment: What do I have to put there? The tar of the git commit? Or unpack the tar to a specific folder?

Comment: File defined in Bazel workspace rule

Comment: There isn't a filename, only the filename to download. But should I unpack it? What, if this package needs also depencencies to download?

Comment: No - no Need to umpacken

Comment: So simply download https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/archive/" + tensorflow_commit + ".tar.gz und copy it into that directory? WIll try it....

Comment: Worked, thanks :) But it needs a few runs to find all dependencies.